# Option where option writer determines type of option to give to holder

Tags: options, option-pricing, european-options, exotics

I am currently looking at an exotic option that allows the holder, at some time $\tau$, to receive either a call or put — the choice of which is decided by the option *writer* — of which both have the same expiry $T>\tau$ and strike $K$.

Is there a name for this kind of option (I searched up chooser options but it doesn't match the definition)?

Also, why would anyone want to purchase such a option? I guess at the end of the day this option should be a linear combination of European options, but I am not sure how to prove this rigorously, any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: Indeed https://ramurapt.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/chooseroptions.doc Mark Rubinstein "Options for the Undecided," _Risk Magazine_, 4(4) discusses "chooser" options where the option holder, rather than the option writer, decides whether the option will become a put or a call.

Comment: @DimitriVulis hi, I’ve just read through the doc and it definitely makes a lot more sense when the option holder makes the choice, but under what circumstances would it make sense to purchase one where the option writer makes the decision?

Comment: Under the assumption that the writer will always choose the least valuable option to the holder, which is likely to be tail risk hedge. And perhaps it is cheaper for the holder than buying a tail risk hedge outright at a given point in time? Off the top of my head, otherwise I agree it is somewhat unusual.